# Populating a list box with data from worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I currently get the following error when I run the code (shown below)

```
Type Mismatch
```

To give a bit of context, the worksheet CourseSelection has row 3 populated from A to F. I would like to put the entries from A2:A6 into a listbox. However, I want to generalize this process and make it dynamic to include additional categories if they are added after column F. Therefore I need an automatic way to do this through code similar to what I have below. However, I am getting error messages and I am unsure why.

I defined TaskList as a Range prior to this code. When I hover over xlToRight when I run the code I see a very large negative value `(-4191)`. I am unsure if this is part of the problem.

```
With Worksheets(CourseSelection).Range("A3")
    Set TaskList = Range(.Offset(0, 1), .End(xlToRight))
End With

frmTaskSelection.lbTasks.RowSource = TaskList
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have CourseSelection defined as a constant returning an existing worksheet name then the code will fail on `With Worksheets(CourseSelection).Range("A3")`. If you want to work with a sheet name CourseSelection you would use `With Worksheets("CourseSelection").Range("A3")`.

Given you error message though you appear to have gotten past this point and your code appears to be failing on `frmTaskSelection.lbTasks.RowSource = TaskList`. This is because RowSource expects **an address**

If you were looking to populate the values from a sheet called CourseSelection from A3 to Ax where x is the last used cell, then this code will work from any active sheet.

*Please note thate I was unclear as to how you wanted to use further values from column F in addition to A2:A6. If you can provide further guidance/picture etc then the code below can be adapted to suit*

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set ws = Worksheets("CourseSelection")
    Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.[a3], ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    frmTaskSelection.lbTasks.RowSource = "'" & ws.Name & "'!" & rng1.Address
    frmTaskSelection.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: It almost works... I did this: Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.Range("A3").Offset(0, 1), ws.Range("A3").End(xlToRight)) ... Unfortunately it only shows entry A4 and does not show them all. Do you know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: This code will look to select from B3 to the first blank cell in row 3. But a listbox takes a vertical list, so if you want to use a horizontal list then you will need to transpose it.