# Selecting entire row of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a row of data (A3 to A11) that I would like to select (there are no blanks in this range). I am using the following code:

```
Range(ws.Range("A3"), ws.Range("A3").End(xlToRight)).Select
```

However, this code is only selecting cell A3 and not A3 to A11. I have also tried xlToLeft and that still only selects A3 as well...How can I correct this? Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Just because of your title, here are a couple ways to select a row

```
ws.Rows(3).Select
ws.Range("a3").EntireRow.Select
```

to select all the data on a row,

```
ws.Range("A3",ws.Cells(3,ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Select
```

Also in your example, you're missing the "ws." prefix from the outermost range object - without specifying the worksheet, Excel will try to refer to the ActiveSheet and you've just written a potential bug.

Answer (score 1):

I think this overlaps with [Populating a list box with data from worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884773/populating-a-list-box-with-data-from-worksheet). I suggest you continue any issues related to this thread back in the original posting

As per prior question to select vertically you use xlDown and xlUp (not xltoRight or xltoLeft)

```
ws.Range(ws.[a3], ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
```

Comment: he says he want to select A3 to A11 and you did not mention any 11 over there I suspect it may also select 12 and 13 rows if they contain any values !

Comment: Yes Niko, my code looks up not down so if there are additional values beyond A11 it will pick them up. This is deliberate as looking down (a) skips blanks (although in this case there are none) (b) selects all the way down if there are no values beneath the first cell. If a hardcoded range is called for then your suggestion does the trick (but no need to Select)

Comment: nice work! I just wanted to make him sure how to select the range but I like your solution +

Answer (score 1):

To select entire row Dynamically(current active cell), Try Below VBA code snippet:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection).EntireRow.Select
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select range from A3 to A11. This would do the trick

```
  activesheet.range("A3:A11").select  or
  activesheet.range(cells(3,"A"),cells(11,"A")).select  or
  activesheet.range(cells(3,1),cells(11,1)).select
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
a = Range("A11").End(xlToRight).Address
Range("A3:" & a).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RANGE("A1", Cells(RANGE("A23").row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Select    'YES
```

Comment: Please briefly explain your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireRow.Select

Comment: Please explain your solution briefly. Please take some time to read how to write a good answer. read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/338114) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)