# VBA - Macro That Finds Specified Header, Filters Values in Various Sheets where Column Locations Change

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to figure out a Macro that will do the following:

1) Find a specified header (ie: "status")
2) Filter this column to a specified value (ie: "discontinued")
3) Once filtered, find another specified column (ie: "replaced with")

The challenge for me is I can't figure out how to set it so the column "Field" is variable to the sheet its on.

I have multiple files that have the "status" header in different locations, (one file has it in column c, another in column f, etc). Is there a way to have excel find that specific column in each sheet is and filter it?

Comment: You should at least show that you tried to solve this yourself. E.g. which part of the programming code are you able to figure out by yourself? At which point do you get stuck exactly? Perhaps you should only ask about (1) and only ask about (2) after getting an answer to (1) and finding out that (2) is still a problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Find a specified header**

You would implement this quite exactly as you'd subconsciously do in your head while "finding a specific header": iterate all columns from left to right until you find it, ...and throw a fit when it's not there. The function should be generic enough to not be attached to any specific worksheet, so you should pass it a worksheet as a parameter.

Something like this:

```
'returns column number of specified header, or -1 if not found.
Public Function FindHeader(sheet As Worksheet, header As String) As Integer
    ...
End Function
```

Find your header row, and loop through the non-empty cells. Your exit conditions would be either you've iterated all non-empty cells in the header row, or you've found a cell that matches the content you're looking for. When the loop exits, you need to know two things: whether the header was found, and if it was, under which column.

**Filter this column for a specified value**

You don't say how the value gets specified, so I'll assume all you need is a `Sub` that takes an `Integer` for the header column to filter, and a `String` parameter for the value to filter with. Using `AutoFilter` -related methods should get you there. Again you want to be able to use this code for any sheet, so pass one as a parameter:

```
Public Sub FilterForSpecificValue(sheet As Worksheet, columnIndex As Integer, filter As String)
    ...
End Sub
```

**Find another specified column**

Well, just reuse the function from #1, passing it the same sheet with another column header:

```
result = FindHeader(ActiveSheet, "AnotherHeader")
```

That's about as much as I can give you for the question you've asked; feel free to ask SO for any **specific programming issues** you might encounter implementing this. However it's possible you won't even need to ask, because it's very likely that somebody else somewhere has documented exactly how to do it - here are a couple links that can help you:

- [Selecting an entire row of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885282/selecting-entire-row-of-data) (StackOverflow)
- [Looping Through a Range of cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353(v=office.11).aspx) (MSDN)
- [StringContainsAny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893280/excel-vba-like-operator/17893442#17893442) (StackOverflow)
- [AutoFilter Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844(v=office.11).aspx) (MSDN)