# Excel VBA like operator

Tags: string, vba, excel

I am using excel VBA to search for a substring in another string as below.

```
Dim pos As Integer
pos = InStr("I am studying at University of Texas at Arlington", "University of Texas")
```

If `pos` returns a non-negative value, it means I have the substring in the string.
However, **I need a more sophisticated search, where the substring can be "Univ of Tex"**:

```
InStr("I am studying at University of Texas at Arlington", "Univ of Tex")
```

Doesn't work for that.

Based on the maximum search terms, I need to say the substring is present. Is it possible using excel VBA?

Comment: Yes. Now did you have a specific programming question?

Comment: I am using excel-vba for programming. I am trying to achieve the like operator functionality as in sql query in excel-vba. I don't know why it is minus 1ed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `Like` operator is already available in VBA:

```
If "I am studying at University of Texas at Arlington" Like "*Univ*of*Texas*" Then
    MsgBox "Yes, it is!"
End If
```

Comment: Good catch! In this situation it's exactly the thing to do. However `Like` is often misused to other ends best served with a function like I'm suggesting, which is why I tend to avoid it, I guess I've seen it abused too many times... (+1)

Comment: Yes, it can certainly be abused. Often (with database-tables) people try to create search-features which are too broad, when they should first reduce the rows-to-search with criteria on other fields.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
Public Function StringContainsAny(string_source As String, _
                                  ByVal caseSensitive As Boolean, _
                                  ParamArray find_values()) As Boolean

    Dim i As Integer, found As Boolean

    If caseSensitive Then

        For i = LBound(find_values) To UBound(find_values)
            found = (InStr(1, string_source, _
                find_values(i), vbBinaryCompare) <> 0)
            If found Then Exit For
        Next

    Else

        For i = LBound(find_values) To UBound(find_values)
            found = (InStr(1, LCase$(string_source), _ 
                LCase$(find_values(i)), vbBinaryCompare) <> 0)
            If found Then Exit For
        Next

    End If

    StringContainsAny = found

End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim SomeString As String
SomeString = "I am studying at University of Texas at Arlington"

Debug.Print StringContainsAny(SomeString, False, "university of texas") 'True
Debug.Print StringContainsAny(SomeString, True, "university of texas")  'False
Debug.Print StringContainsAny(SomeString, True, "University of Texas")  'True
```

But also:

```
Debug.Print StringContainsAny(SomeString, False, "TEXAS", "SMURF") 'True
```

And:

```
Debug.Print StringContainsAny(SomeString, False, "univ", "of", "tex") 'True
```

Or:

```
Dim Words As String()
Words = Split("univ of tex", " ")
Debug.Print StringContainsAny(SomeString, False, Words) 'True
```

You can specify as many values as you need for `find_values()`, and the function exits on the first match found.

If you specifically want to return `true` when all parts of "Univ of Tex" are found in the string, you'd have to tweak the code a bit, to return `true` *when all passed arguments are found in the string*. But then perhaps the method should be renamed `StringContainsAll` - perhaps something like this:

```
Public Function StringContainsAll(string_source As String, _
                                  ByVal caseSensitive As Boolean, _
                                  ParamArray find_values()) As Boolean

    Dim i As Integer, found As Boolean

    If caseSensitive Then

        For i = LBound(find_values) To UBound(find_values)
            found = (InStr(1, string_source, find_values(i), vbBinaryCompare) <> 0)
            If Not found Then Exit For
        Next

    Else

        For i = LBound(find_values) To UBound(find_values)
            found = (InStr(1, LCase$(string_source), _
                              LCase$(find_values(i)), vbBinaryCompare) <> 0)
            If Not found Then Exit For
        Next

    End If

    StringContainsAll = found

End Function
```

Note that this last snippet isn't tested and doesn't care in what order the words are found in the string.