# How to use Like operator in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro, that counts number of columns in a certain Sheet, then copies this sheet content to Sheet1 inside the same workbook.

```
Sub test()
Dim LastCol As Long
Set currentsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

LastCol = Sheets("APage").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
Sheets("APage").Range("1:1" & LastCol1).Copy
currentsheet.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

The particularity is that sheet names could be: `"APage", "BPage", "10Page"` etc. So first latter can be different, but the `"Page"` always remains in the sheet name. 
How to use correctly a `*` to say in VBA to use all the sheets, named Pages, with any letters at the begging of the sheet name?  Thanks!

Comment: Ale, as I see you tries to copy data from each sheet "*Page" to sheet `Sheet1`. But where you'd like to paste them? in A2 from first sheet, in B2 from second sheet and so on?

Comment: This was just a short example. Actually i paste each "*Page" copied content to O2, Q2, S2, ..Y2 cells.

Comment: one more thins, insted `LastCol = Sheets("APage").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column` I recommend you to use `LastCol = Sheets("APage").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` - it's more reliable

Comment: research first please - duplicate of [Excel VBA like operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893280/excel-vba-like-operator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to loop through all worksheets with wildcard names, you can do something like this:

```
Sub LoopThroughWorksheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name Like "*Page" Then
            'Do whatever with this particular sheet
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Sadly you can't. But you can use code like

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr(ws.Name, "Page") > 0 Then
        'ws is a worksheet with the text 'Page' in its name
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no wildcard search within the `Sheets` collection.  You'll need to iterate through them, for example:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr(ws.Name, "Page") > 0 Then
        ...
    End If
Next
```

Comment: @Bathsheba only because you were editing the question :)

Comment: @Joe Why do you write "no wildcard search".  It seems to work using the Like operator as in  "For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets  If WS.Name Like "*eet*" Then ... "  seems to return all the sheets with eet in the name?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, that's correct,  `Like "*Page"` is the same as `InStr(ws.Name,"Page")>0`.  By "no wildcard search" I meant that you can't do `For each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("*Page")`, which I believe is what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @Joe Ah, now I understand the point you were making.  Thank you for the clarification.