# Excel VBA InStr returns 0 although substring is valid

Tags: vba, excel

In this code, I'm trying to check if the input entered by user (txtList) can be found in a list of data (txtList). The following code returns 0 (substring not found although "John Ho" and "Ho Tee Nee, John" is the exact same person. Can someone please enlighten me on how to resolve this?

```
'code returns 0 (substring not found)
Dim txtList As String, txtInput As String
txtList = "Ho Tee Nee, John"
txtInput = "John Ho"
Debug.Print InStr(1, txtList, txtInput, vbTextCompare)
```

Comment: That is because it is looking for a complete match.  It does not divide the words and look separately.  It must find the complete string in the other string not parts.

Comment: You will need to compare each word separately in two commands then compare that both were found.

Comment: Look at it from a compiler's perspective: what's the difference between `"abc", `"a,b,c"` and `"a/b/c"` string literals? None. All are string literals. There's no way `InStr` can guess what you mean to do with that. Try making a [StringContainsAny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17893442/1188513) function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Split the search criteria and look for each piece.

```
Dim i As Long, txtList As String, txtInput As Variant
txtList = Chr(32) & "Ho Tee Nee, John" & Chr(32)
txtInput = Split("John Ho", Chr(32))

For i = LBound(txtInput) To UBound(txtInput)
    If Not CBool(InStr(1, txtList, Chr(32) & txtInput(i) & Chr(32), vbTextCompare)) Then Exit For
Next i

If i > UBound(txtInput) Then
    Debug.Print "all parts match"
Else
    Debug.Print "incomplete match"
End If
```

This is a case-insensitive search. For a case-sensitive search change vbTextCompare to vbBinaryCompare.

Comment: I bracketed the search criteria and the search string with spaces to provide a 'whole word search'. There might be a problem with *Nee* due to the comma but I'm sure you can account for that with some error control.

Comment: e.g. `txtList = Chr(32) & application.trim(replace("Ho Tee Nee, John", chr(44), chr(32))) & Chr(32)`