# VBA Excel Script - Runtime Error 424 (Code Specific)

Tags: vba, excel

By no means am I a VBA developer, but any help on why this isn't working would be greatly appreciated...

Problem:

1. Analyze all worksheets, except the last.
2. Check if a column I and J contain an X, if they do, get that row and copy it to the last worksheet.

Error Highlighted is at this line: **For Each ws In Workbook.Worksheets**. I'm not sure why.

Below is my code, but it's not compiling, and giving me the error code 424 - Object Required.

```
Sub CopyData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Remediation Summary")

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Index < (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1) Then
'check column i for x
For Each icell In ws.Range("i1:i200").Cells
If icell.Value Like ("X") Or ("x") Then
    Rows(icell.RowIndex).Copy
    pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
Next icell

'check column j for x
For Each jcell In ws.Range("j1:j200").Cells
If jcell.Value Like ("X") Or ("x") Then
    Rows(jcell.RowIndex).Copy
    pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
Next jcell
End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Workbook`?  Do you mean ThisWorkbook or maybe ActiveWorkbook?

Comment: @TimWilliams okay, that solves the 424 error now we are getting "1004: Application-Defined or Object-Defined error"

Comment: @TimWilliams check the updated codebase below

Comment: The 1004, error is coming from For Each icell In ws.Range("i0:i200").Cells, not sure why.

Comment: AFAICT you can't specify an address from row `0`; the first row is labelled `1` in the UI. Try `For Each icell In ws.Range("i1:i200").Cells`.

Comment: iCell.EntireRow.Copy

Comment: @TimWilliams I've got it doing the copy and past action at this point! But it's not copying the entire row appropriately now. It's only copying a number 1 over. Not the actual row.

Answer (score 1):

`Option Explicit` is really a great helper - write it on the top of every module / class / worksheet. It would tell immediately, if there is some variable, which is not declared.

In your case, `ws` should be declared as a worksheet, as far as you are using the for-each loop to go through the Worksheets collection:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Debug.Print ws.Name
    Next ws

End Sub
```

[Option Explicit MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-explicit-statement?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

---

Concerning this part - `If icell.Value Like ("X") Or ("x") Then`, consider rewriting it like this:

`If UCase(icell) = "X" Then`. It would be more understandable and `Like` is not needed when the comparison is without some additional signs `?*`.

[Excel VBA like operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893280/excel-vba-like-operator)

Answer (score 0):

updated codebase:

```
Sub CopyData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Remediation Summary")

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Index < (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1) Then
    'check column i for x
    For Each icell In ws.Range("i0:i200").Cells
    If icell.Value Like ("X") Or ("x") Then
        Rows(icell.RowIndex).Copy
        pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
    Next icell

    'check column j for x
    For Each jcell In ws.Range("j0:j200").Cells
    If jcell.Value Like ("X") Or ("x") Then
        Rows(jcell.RowIndex).Copy
        pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
    Next jcell
End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: This will copy from the ActiveSheet, which may not be ws

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, please try the code below:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim icell As Range
Dim jcell As Range
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Remediation Summary")

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Index < (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1) Then
'check column i for x
For Each icell In ws.Range("i1:i200").Cells
If UCase(icell) = "X" Or UCase(icell) = "x" Then
    pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value = icell.EntireRow.Value
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
Next icell

'check column j for x
For Each jcell In ws.Range("j1:j200").Cells
If UCase(jcell) = "X" Or UCase(jcell) = "x" Then
    pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value = jcell.EntireRow.Value
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
Next jcell
End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub CopyData()

    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, icell As Range
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Remediation Summary") 'ThisWorkbook?

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Index < (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1) Then
            'check column i,j for x
            For Each icell In ws.Range("i1:i200").Cells
                If LCase(icell.Value) = "x" Or LCase(icell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "x" Then
                    pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value = _
                                    icell.EntireRow.Value
                End If
            Next icell
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```