# If file name matches certain criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a piece of code that will execute a certain process if the filename contains a certain string. The filename will always be one long string, hence I would need to probably LookIn to the filename to see if it matches. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub GrabTheData()

    If FileName = "*BV*.xl??" Then
        Workbooks(FileName).Sheets("Property").Copy
        Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").Paste

    ElseIf FileName = "*BV2*.xl??" Then
        Workbooks(FileName).Sheets("Room Class").Copy
        Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet3").Paste

    End If

End Sub
```

This code doesn't accurately identify the filenames, but just skips over to the next. An example of the filename is the following: GaniBV.xlsx
How can i change the code so that it will accurately match the filename with the defined value?

Comment: Where is the code that puts a value in the String variable `FileName` ??

Comment: What you are looking for is `Like` operator. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893280/excel-vba-like-operator and https://analystcave.com/vba-like-operator/

Comment: That's all it was :) Thanks so much Shahkalpesh!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use:

```
Private Sub GrabTheData()

    If FileName Like "*BV*.xl*" Then
        Workbooks(FileName).Sheets("Property").Copy
        Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").Paste

    ElseIf FileName Like "*BV2*.xl*" Then
        Workbooks(FileName).Sheets("Room Class").Copy
        Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet3").Paste

    End If

End Sub
```