# Using wildcards with the IF statement

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the below code in my VBA but it is not working, I have a lot or cells containing HFMWO123455 ect, the numbers keep changing. Any help appreciated.

```
If ((.Cells(K, "E").Value = "HFMWO*")) Then
    J = J + 1
    .Rows(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Facilities").Range("A" & J + 1)
    .Rows(K).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Comment: Have a look at the `Like` operator, like here: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893280/excel-vba-like-operator".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `Like` operator for wildcard comparisons.

```
If .Cells(K, "E").Value LIKE "HFMWO*" Then
    J = J + 1
    .Rows(K).EntireRow.Copy _
       Destination:=Worksheets("Facilities").Range("A" & J + 1) 
    .Rows(K).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple ways.  If you're only checking if a substring exists within a string, try this:

```
If Instr(SearchString, target) then
    ' Do stuff
End If
```

Alternatively, you can use "Like":

```
If SearchString LIKE "*" &target & "*" Then
    'Do stuff
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim j As Long, k As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- Change sheet name to fit your needs

        If InStr(1, .Cells(k, "E").Value, "HFMWO", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            j = j + 1
            .Rows(k).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Facilities").Range("A" & j + 1)
            .Rows(k).EntireRow.Delete
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

**Notes:**

- If you loop aiming to delete rows, loop from bottom to top.

Comment: It's not case sensitive if you add the comparemode:=vbtextcompare argument.

Comment: @user11217663 you are absolutely right. i have edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Like operator for this.

```
'Public Sub StringLike()
'    Dim K As Long: K = 1
'    Dim J As Long: J = 1
'    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If .Cells(K, "E").Value Like "HFMWO*" Then
            J = J + 1
            .Rows(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Facilities").Range("A" & J + 1)
            .Rows(K).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
'    End With
'End Sub
```

Note that I added some lines to make the code testable but commented out them as you won't need them when inserting into your file.

By the way, in the future, please include such code examples in your questions that can be tested easily.