# Check if cell contains a specific substring

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop through the cells in a column and check if each cell contain a specific substring.

I have the code for the exact search but I don't know how to search for a substring

```
Sub Macro1()
    For i = 2 To 2500
        If Cells(i, 7).Value = "ALSO DEUTSCHLAND GMBHLMP" Then
            Cells(i, 2).Value = "sometext"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

A substring search for LMP should also give the above output.

Comment: The [`InStr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) function.

Comment: @BigBen For me, that's a totally right answer.

Comment: I quite like using LIKE on the rare occasion I have to do something like this because I always get Instr arguments the wrong way round, whichever way i try.

Comment: @SJR and I got the order mixed up originally too :)

Comment: you could also do this with a formula, no need for vba

Answer (score 4):

Use [`InStr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) to test if a `String` contains a sub-string.

```
If InStr(1, Cells(i, 7).Value, "LMP", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
```

You have several options for the string comparison (last argument):

> `vbUseCompareOption`: Performs a comparison by using the setting of the **Option Compare** statement.
>
> `vbBinaryCompare`: Performs a binary comparison.
>
> `vbTextCompare`: Performs a textual comparison.

I have proposed `vbBinaryCompare` assuming you want this to be *case-sensitive*.

NOTE: You can use `Like` as well, as demonstrated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893280/excel-vba-like-operator).

Comment: I know OP hasn't requested it but might be worth adding `textcompare` to `InStr`.. eradicates the case sensitive issue

Comment: True.. but I suspect that question is coming somewhere down the line :)

Comment: Just a small doubt when it is searching LMP as a substring will it consider as a single word or three separate Letters.

Comment: It will look for the letters LMP as a string, not 3 separate letters.

Comment: Its throwing a run time error 13. Type Mismatch                                                          Below is the code I wrote,  Also is there a way to remove case sensitiveness while using Like                                                                                                For i = 2 To 2500
If InStr(Cells(i, 7).Value, "Amazon", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
Cells(i, 2).Value = "Amazon"
End If
Next i

Comment: Do you have any errors or non-text values in the row? What is the specific value of `Cells(i, 7)` that causes the error? Also - change to `vbTextCompare` from `vbBinaryCompare`. Or, is your question about case sensitivity with `Like`?

Comment: I tried with vbTextCompare as well, its still the same error, well none of the rows are blanks, but the strings do contain numbers. (i,7) has value as of now "ACORD-92 d.o.o."

Comment: What is the *specific* value of `Cells(i, 7)` that throws the error?

Comment: (i,7) has value "ACORD-92 d.o.o.
"

Comment: Use the latest edit, sorry. You need to specify the start position as well if you're using the last argument, `InStr(1, Cells(i, 7).Value, "Amazon", vbBinaryCompare)`

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use the [find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) method of a range like that

```
Sub FindIt()

    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("G2:G2500")

    Dim fndRg As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    With rg

        Set fndRg = .Find("ALSO DEUTSCHLAND GMBHLMP", , xlValues)

        If Not fndRg Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = fndRg.Address
            Do
                fndRg.Offset(, -5).Value = "some text"
                Set fndRg = .FindNext(fndRg)
            Loop While Not fndRg Is Nothing And fndRg.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: No reason, I just do not really know  for what the OP is relly looking for.