# Look through list and move rows meeting criteria to another sheet on Excel VBA Type Mistmatch

Tags: vba, excel

Sheet 1 has a list of names in column A. Sheet 2 has cells that have such names in column B. For every name in column A sheet 1 also found in column B sheet 2, I am trying to move to sheet 3. Right now I am getting a type mismatch error on "If rng = lookupvalue Then". Both those columns are formatted as text so I cannot understand why...

```
Sub FIXSICC()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet


Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")


z = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = z To 2 Step -1
    lookupvalue = ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        For x = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            Set rng = ws2.Cells(x, 2)
            If rng = lookupvalue Then
                ws1.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=ws3.range("A" & ws3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End If
        Next x
Next i


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Dim rng as Range, and try using rng.Value perhaps. Does that change anything?

Comment: the type mismatch error still appears.

Comment: What are the values of `rng` and `lookupvalue` when you get the error ?

Comment: it was showing me a type mismatch error on one of the line items. Ran it again today and it runs fine. Thanks tho

Comment: actually do you have any advice on:

ws1.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=ws3.range("A" & ws3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

It's only pasting one column an not the entire row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try something like this : If cstr(rng.value)=cstr(lookupvalue)
I try to run your code just now but no error appear. I wonder why.

Comment: strange it didn't work yesterday, but the same code works today. Thanks for the suggestion tho

Comment: actually do you have any advice on:

ws1.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=ws3.range("A" & ws3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

It's only pasting one column an not the entire row.

Comment: Sorry..I don't get your question. Could you be more specifics? Did you mean that information from "Sheet1" copy to "Sheet3"? Because I tested your code, all the information from "Sheet1" is pasting in "Sheet3" except for the first row  in "Sheet1".

Comment: it copies and pastes only one cell when i want the whole row to be copied and pasted.

Comment: maybe you can refer to this link [Selecting entire row of data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885282/selecting-entire-row-of-data)